# Using Personal Dictionary files

Tags: hunspell

The man page mentions the "Personal dictionary file" ...
https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man4/hunspell.4.html

> Personal  dictionaries  are  simple  word  lists. Asterisk at the
> first character position signs prohibition.  A second word separated
> by a slash sets the affixation.

If I can include those words in the main Dictionary file, why would anyone use personal file? Is any language using this?

Comment: The default dictionary file will be overwritten when the application (to which the file belongs) updates. Having a personal file ensures that your changes (data) isn't lost during such upgrades

Comment: And how do I install personal files?

Comment: You don't install personal files. There're a couple of handy ways of moving around those files. (1) Move/copy those files individually after installing the software. (2) Have the personal files in common fileshare and have a shell script copy it during the software install.